# How can I create a variable that can be edited in other modules without being global?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a game and I have a global `save` variable that holds the various aspects of the game (units, upgrades, etc). The game code is separated into several modules, such as upgrades or achievements.

How can I make the `save` variable accessible in the other modules? Importing gives me a read-only copy of the variable, which is not useful. How can I share the variable with the other modules without making it global?

I'm not looking for the easiest solution to the problem, I'm looking for best practices.

EDIT: I'm using ES6 import/export functionality.

Comment: You could look at [dependency injection](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Dependency-injection-in-JavaScript).

Comment: Ajax + server side persistence ?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I just added some additional info in the question. Apologies for being so broad!

Comment: How is `save` "read-only"? Can you give a small example of how you drew this conclusion?

Comment: @Katana314 It's not that `save` is read-only, it's that when you `import save` it's read-only.

Comment: @CalebAnthony I know. I am asking how you drew the conclusion that once imported, it can't be modified or that its changes don't reflect on its origin.

Comment: @Katana314 I read through [this](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) article.

Comment: @CalebAnthony Thanks. Jacob summarized what I was going to say - the individual variables can't be modified with an `x = y` operation, but they can be altered in other ways. So, simply calling them "read-only" isn't the best description in my view. (I honestly think the article you linked is not as clear as it could be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing may give you a read-only copy of the variable, but an imported object is not *immutable*. Therefore, if you want to share a state object of sorts that multiple modules can write to, you can:

```
import saveState from './saveState';

saveState = { world: { } }; // Doesn't work
saveState.world = {};       // Does work
```

...not that I'd advocate such a pattern (shared state leads to all kinds of upredictability). Better to have a shared object with methods and have that object maintain an internal state.

Comment: Honestly, for the purposes of a video game, I would say open access is probably simplest. It makes it really easy to check things like `if (saveState.world['dragonChoice'] === 'SAVE') { dialog = "I heard you saved that dragon." }`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using es6, you can create a local module variable and only export utility functions to change the original value.

```
// save-module.js
let Save = {
  score: 0,
  room: 'main'
}

export changeRoom(room){
  Save.room = room;
}
export addScore(){
  Save.score++;
}
export subtractScore(){
  Save.score--;
}
export getSaveObject(){
  return Save;
}

// other-module.js
import { changeRoom, addScore, subtractScore, getSaveObject } from './save-module';

// Do something here with the fns and it should update the Save variable
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to implement this when you have objects nested 3 levels deep?